# AWSCognito のログイン画面のサイズを変更したい。

Tags: swift, ios, aws

当方、AWSCognitoは初めて使用し、コードを引き継ぎしたため、
的はずれな質問をしていたら、申し訳ありません。
スマートフォン（iPhone）からAWSCognitoを使って、
ログインする処理を実装してるのですが、ログインページが
小さいと言われ、大きくしたいと思っているのですが、
クライアントのコードは、以下のようになっており、

```
if (!self.appDelegate.auth.isSignedIn) {        
　　　　self.appDelegate.auth.getSession  { (session:AWSCognitoAuthUserSession?, error:Error?) in
      if(error != nil) {
           self.appDelegate.session = nil
           self.alertWithTitle("Error", message: (error! as NSError).userInfo["error"] as? String)
           print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
      } else {
      　　　self.appDelegate.session = session
           print("Login!")
           let idToken = self.appDelegate.session?.idToken?.tokenString
           let accessToken = self.appDelegate.session?.accessToken?.tokenString
           let refreshToken = self.appDelegate.session?.refreshToken?.tokenString

           print("idToken: \(idToken!)")

           UserDefaults.standard.set(idToken, forKey: Constants.cognitoIdToken)
           UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken, forKey: Constants.cognitoAccessToken)
           UserDefaults.standard.set(refreshToken, forKey: Constants.cognitoRefreshToken)
       }
       self.requestOrganization()
   }

} else {
    self.appDelegate.auth.signOut { (error:Error?) in
    if(error != nil){
        self.alertWithTitle("Error", message: (error! as NSError).userInfo["error"] as? String)
    }else {
        self.appDelegate.session = nil
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: Constants.cognitoIdToken)
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: Constants.cognitoAccessToken)
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: Constants.cognitoRefreshToken)

        let url = URL(string: "https://accounts.google.com/Logout")!
        let controller = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        controller.delegate = self
    }
}
```

ログアウトページの指定はあるのですが、
ログインページの指定がありません。
このため、サイズを変更出来ず困っております。

ログインページなどは、AWSCognitoの管理ページなどで作成できるのでしょうか？

Comment: ***ログインページなどは、AWSCognitoの管理ページなどで作成できるのでしょうか？*** 「作成」はできませんが、CSSを使ってある程度のカスタマイズはできるようです。[Customizing the Built-in Sign-in and Sign-up Webpages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html)、[組み込みのサインインおよびサインアップウェブページのカスタマイズ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html)。自分で使ってみたわけでも無いし、あなたのアプリに適用できるかも不明ですが、一度試してみられてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます！
一つの回避策として検討してみますー。